# Wrap gutenberg block ‘div’ in other elements/extra HTML

Tags: functions, filters, html, block-editor

I’m trying to add HTML wrappers around a block to create a clipping effect, something like the below code. It has been suggested this might be possible with the block save or block edit functions?

I have done a fair bit of experimenting with CSS clip-path and SVG clipPath and unfortunately they will not work for what I am trying to achieve as I need cross-browser support.

HTML:

```
<div class="transform-containter">
<div class="transform-right">
<div class="transform-left">
<div class="transform-content">
<div class="block-container">
BLOCK CONTENT HERE
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.transform-containter {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.transform-right {
    position: relative;
    width: 110%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: -5%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(2deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(2deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(2deg);
    transform: rotate(2deg);
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top:2.5%;
}
.transform-left {
    position: relative;
    width: 110%;
    height: 100%;
    left: -5%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-4deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-4deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-4deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-4deg);
    transform: rotate(-4deg);
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: -4%;
    margin-bottom: 3.5%;
}
.transform-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(2deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(2deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(2deg);
    transform: rotate(2deg);
    background-color: #cccccc;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 2% 0 -2% 0;
    padding: 2em 10%;
}
```

Here is a codepen of the effect in raw HTML/CSS https://codepen.io/bearandpear/pen/VObzQZ

So essentially just trying to add the extra HTML div elements either side of the block output code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I’m not a developer, I’m pretty good with HTML, CSS and a little PHP, but completely green when it comes to Javascript/React…

Comment: note that you can create that HTML structure using only group blocks in the block editor, without writing any code. 5 group blocks, each with their class set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When registering a block we indicate: an **edit** property which defines how the block acts/displays in the editor, and a **save** property which is responsible for the final HTML of the block.

To modify these two functions from a block we need to use [filter hooks](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/filters/block-filters/). These hooks just need to be included inside a script in the editor.

The [getSaveElement](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/filters/block-filters/#blocks-getsaveelement) filter lets us modify the HTML output of the save property of the block. Using JSX:

```js
const modifySaveHtml = (block, props, attributes) => {
    if (props.name !== "my-plugin/my-block") {
        return block;
    }

    return (
        <div className="transform-container">
            <div className="transform-right">
                <div className="transform-left">
                    <div className="transform-content">{block}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
wp.hooks.addFilter(
    "blocks.getSaveElement",
    "my-plugin/modifySaveHtml",
    modifySaveHtml
);
```

Using JS (ES5):

```js
var createElement = wp.element.createElement;

var modifySaveHtml = function(block, props, attributes) {
    if (props.name !== "my-plugin/my-block") {
        return block;
    }

    return createElement(
        "div",
        { className: "transform-container" },
        createElement(
            "div",
            { className: "transform-right" },
            createElement(
                "div",
                { className: "transform-left" },
                createElement("div", { className: "transform-content" }, block)
            )
        )
    );
};
wp.hooks.addFilter(
    "blocks.getSaveElement",
    "my-plugin/modifySaveHtml",
    modifySaveHtml
);
```

The [editor.BlockEdit](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/filters/block-filters/#editor-blockedit) filter modifies the HTML of the edit property of the block. This might not be necessary if you don't need to modify the HTML in the editor. Using JSX:

```js
const modifyEditHtml = BlockEdit => {
    return props => {
        if (props.name !== "my-plugin/my-block") {
            return <BlockEdit {...props} />;
        }

        return (
            <div className="transform-container">
                <div className="transform-right">
                    <div className="transform-left">
                        <div className="transform-content">
                            <BlockEdit {...props} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    };
};
wp.hooks.addFilter(
    "editor.BlockEdit",
    "my-plugin/modifyEditHtml",
    modifyEditHtml
);
```

Using JS (ES5):

```js
var createElement = wp.element.createElement;

var modifyEditHtml = function(BlockEdit) {
    return function(props) {
        if (props.name !== "my-plugin/my-block") {
            return createElement( BlockEdit, props );
        }

        return createElement(
            "div",
            { className: "transform-container" },
            createElement(
                "div",
                { className: "transform-right" },
                createElement(
                    "div",
                    { className: "transform-left" },
                    createElement(
                        "div",
                        { className: "transform-content" },
                        createElement(
                            BlockEdit,
                            props
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
    };
};
wp.hooks.addFilter(
    "editor.BlockEdit",
    "my-plugin/modifyEditHtml",
    modifyEditHtml
);
```

Keep in mind that these filters will be applied to both new instances of the block and old ones. This means that any block which was created previously will show an "invalid content" message. This is because the filter modifies the block definition and it now expects the new HTML which is not there, as the block was created/saved before applying the filter.

When enqueuing your script (from PHP), remember to include the used dependencies. In the above code, `wp-hooks` package is used and `wp-element` as well in the non-JSX code.

```
function my_plugin_enqueue_editor() {

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'my-plugin-script', // name
        'path/to/my-plugin-script.js', // path
        array( // dependencies
            'wp-element',
            'wp-hooks',
        ),
        '1.0.0', // my-plugin version number
        true // enqueue in the footer.
    );

}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'my_plugin_enqueue_editor' );
```

Note: The JS(ES5) code is untested but I think it should work correctly.

Comment: This is great, thank you Alvaro. This all seems to make sense (and probably works perfectly), but due to my own inexperience I could't quite figure out how to get this to work when hooking into an existing plugin.
I have however managed a work-around by building my own very simple container block plugin with all of the HTML wrappers needed (using innerBlocks and align-full), which I can insert the other blocks into.

Comment: @bearandpear You just need to add the code in the same script you are using to add your custom block. Can you share how you are adding that script (the PHP function)?

Comment: does this code go in the JS file or the PHP file? I was inserting it in the JS file which is called up in my plugin's PHP file... 
`function bp_block_container_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'bp-block-container-script',
        plugins_url( 'bpblockcontainer.js', __FILE__ )
    );
}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'bp_block_container_enqueue' ); `

Comment: @bearandpear the code from the answer goes in that JS file. But you need to modify your [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) call to include the `'wp-hooks'` dependency. When using any of the Gutenberg packages (`wp.editor`, `wp.blocks`, etc.) you need to include those dependencies in your script enqueue (remember that the JS object `wp.hooks` belongs to the dependency `wp-hooks`). See an example of adding a Gutenberg dependency [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/javascript/extending-the-block-editor/).

Comment: I have added 'wp-hooks' to the wp_enqueue_script like this... `function bp_block_container_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'bp-block-container-script',
        plugins_url( 'bpblockcontainer.js', __FILE__ )
    );
}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'bp_block_container_enqueue' );
add_action( 'wp-hooks', 'bp_block_container/modifySaveHtml' );
add_action( 'wp-hooks', 'bp_block_container/modifyEditHtml' );`
but I keep getting this in the console... 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <' I am clearly doing something wrong in the JS?

Comment: @bearandpear You don't need those two `add_action( 'wp-hooks'`...  In your case it would be: `function bp_block_container_enqueue() { wp_enqueue_script( 'bp-block-container-script', plugins_url( 'bpblockcontainer.js', __FILE__ ), array ('wp-hooks' ) ); } add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'bp_block_container_enqueue' );`. But the issue you are having is that you are using JSX syntax in your JS file. JSX needs to be compiled to JS with Babel. It's a [big topic](https://css-tricks.com/learning-gutenberg-4-modern-javascript-syntax/#article-header-id-4).If you need any pointer let me know.

Comment: Yeah big topic indeed... I think I'll need to somehow either compile this as a separate file or re-write the existing script in JSX. It is all a bit beyond me at the moment. I will go back to the drawing board and try to create a block plugin from scratch rather than edit an existing one. Thank you so much for your help, I am just too new to the whole JSX/react/babel environment at the moment.

Comment: @bearandpear I included a non-JSX version in the answer and extended the explanation on the script dependencies. JSX can be difficult at first, but if you are getting deeper into JavaScript with Gutenberg it is worth learning it. If you follow that path I suggest `parcel` over `webpack` as it is easier to set up. Hope it helps!

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you so much for persevering! I will try to add to the editor as well based on the JS code you have provided. I really do appreciate the help, I have learnt so much just from this one issue. I am new to JS in all of its forms, but currently trying to build a block from scratch following some tuts so I will stick at it and learn JSX—I've just set up node etc. so the fun can now begin!

Comment: Sorry to ask but is there a simple way to add this content to the editor with JS? I can't figure out how to rewrite the JSX in JS, keeps throwing up errors...

Comment: You can include the JS part above (I only indicated the plain JS for `blocks.getSaveElement`, Ill add the one for `editor.BlockEdit`) The JSX needs to be compiled ("transformed") into JS in your PC and then the browser reads the already compiled (only JS) file. I used some features that usually get transformed as well, like [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) or [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). I'll edit the plain JS part.

Comment: You are an absolute legend! Thank you so much, this works perfectly. Is there any way I can show some appreciation? A plugin page I can review or beer tokens or something?

Comment: Would there happen to be a YouTube tutorial on this same process?

Answer (score 0):

You can create divs inside divs (or different elements) in the Gutenberg edit/save function. Like so:

```
createElement( "div",
               {className: "transform-containter"},
                createElement( "div",
                               {className: "transform-right"},
                                createElement( "div",
                                                {className: "transform-left"},
                          [AND SO ON...]
                               YOUR BLOCK CONTENT
                                )
                )
)
```

I think you try to write your own block, or am I wrong?

Comment: Thank you for this. I am actually trying to add these elements to an existing block, as I am not fluent enough in javascript/react to create one from scratch.

Is there a way to add this code to an existing block externally, or would this only work if I write one from scratch?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know a way to hook into a block or extend it anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

You could also wrap your gutenberg block via WP PHP filter:

```
<?php

add_filter( 'render_block', [$this, 'wp_gutenberg_wrap_block'], 10, 2 );

function wp_gutenberg_wrap_block( $block_content, $block ) {
    $align_class = 'default';
    $alignment   = $block['attrs']['align'] ?? 'default';

    if ( $alignment === 'full' ) {
        $align_class = 'alignfull';
    }

    if ( $alignment === 'wide' ) {
        $align_class = 'alignwide';
    }

    $wrapper = "<section class='block_wrapper $align_class'>";
    $wrapper .= $block_content;
    $wrapper .= '</section>';

    return $wrapper;
}
```